# Checking if an array contains all the elements

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers, compare

I wrote a Code that reads from a txt.file stores it into an array , remove the spaces then print them out.
I want to add another functionality. This time is to check if the user provided the right input file.
I want to compare the array reds with the array stringcard and see if the array red contains all the elements of the array stringcard.
I have been searching on the internet for a while but I don't know how to solve this problem.

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <string.h> 
#include <stdlib.h>
#define max 13
#define stringlength 8
const char *stringcard[] = {
  "REDA",
  "RED2",
  "RED3",
  "RED4",
  "RED5",
  "RED6",
  "RED7",
  "RED8",
  "RED9",
  "RED10",
  "REDJ",
  "REDQ",
  "REDK",
};
char * removechar(char str[], int ch) {

  char * cpos = str;

  while ((cpos = strchr(cpos, ch))) {
    strcpy(cpos, cpos + 1);
  }
  return str;
}

int main(int argc, char ** argv) {

  char * reds[max];

  int i;

  FILE * file = argc > 1 ? fopen(argv[1], "r") : stdin;
  if (file == NULL)
    return 1;
  if (argc != 2) {
    printf("[ERR]");
    return 0;
  }

  for (i = 0; i < max; i++) {

    reds[i] = malloc(stringlength);
    fgets(reds[i], stringlength, file);

  }

  for (i = 0; i < max; i++) {

    printf("%s", reds[i]);

  }

  // removes spaces
  for (i = 0; i < max; i++) {

    removechar(reds[i], ' ');

  }

  for (i = 0; i < max; i++) {

    printf("%s", reds[i]);

  }

int success = 1;
size_t size = sizeof(stringcard)/sizeof(stringcard[0]); 
size_t size2 = sizeof(reds)/sizeof(reds[0]);

if(size == size2)
{
    for(int i = 0; i<size;i++)
    {
        if(strcmp(stringcard[i], reds[i]) != 0){ 
            success = 0; 
        printf("nope");
            break; 
            }
    }




}

      return 0;

}
```

Input:

```
RED A
RED 2
RED 3
RED 4
RED 5
RED 6
RED 7
RED 8
RED 9
RED 10
RED J
RED Q
RED K
```

Comment: Count the number of elements that match between the two arrays. If it's the same as the size of the array, they contain the same elements.

Comment: Where is your code ?

Comment: What does this: `FILE * file = argc > 1 ? fopen(argv[1], "r") : stdin;` do?

Comment: @P__J__ please take a look at my edit.

Comment: @ryyker opens the file and goes to read mode

Comment: @Barmar please take a look at my edit. Is this what you mean?

Comment: If the file is "correct", do the elements [in `reds`] have to be in the same order [as the elements in `stringcard`]? This is easy. Or, is the problem more complex (i.e.) the file is correct if all cards are there _but_ can be in _any_ order? The same order is implied by your example input, but _"the array red contains all the elements of the array stringcard"_ implies the latter/more general requirement.

Comment: @CraigEstey no the input can be in any order

Comment: @momonosuke can you have a lot of elements to compare ? If yes to do fast it is better to sort the values, else no.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is prefaced by my top comments.

This should work for cards in any order:

```
size_t size = sizeof(stringcard) / sizeof(stringcard[0]);
size_t size2 = sizeof(reds) / sizeof(reds[0]);

int allmatch = 0;
if (size == size2) {
    allmatch = 1;

    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
        int curmatch = 0;
        const char *curcard = &stringcard[i];

        for (int j = 0; j < size; ++j) {
            if (strcmp(curcard, reds[j]) == 0) {
                curmatch = 1;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (! curmatch) {
            allmatch = 0;
            break;
        }
    }
}

printf("RESULT: %s\n",allmatch ? "MATCH" : "NOMATCH");
```

---

**UPDATE:**

> if we know reds is sorted compare the result of strcmp with -1 or 1 rather than 0 depending on the order of the sorted elements. If stringcard is sorted of course exchange the roles

Okay, if we assume `stringcard` is *always* sorted [or we choose to pre-sort it], we can add an early escape to the inner loop that can save a small amount of time for the failed case:

```
size_t size = sizeof(stringcard) / sizeof(stringcard[0]);
size_t size2 = sizeof(reds) / sizeof(reds[0]);

int allmatch = 0;
if (size == size2) {
    allmatch = 1;

    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
        int curmatch = 0;
        char *redcard = reds[i];

        for (int j = 0; j < size; ++j) {
            int cmpflg = strcmp(redcard,stringcard[j]);

            if (cmpflg == 0) {
                curmatch = 1;
                break;
            }

            if (cmpflg > 0)
                break;
        }

        if (! curmatch) {
            allmatch = 0;
            break;
        }
    }
}

printf("RESULT: %s\n",allmatch ? "MATCH" : "NOMATCH");
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. When I compile it says `allmatch` is an unused variable. And if i add a printf before `allmatch=0` , I still get the result that the strings are not equal

Comment: _stringcard[i]_ can be saved in a var, this improve a little the code

Comment: additional remark : if we know _reds_ is sorted compare the result of strcmp with -1 or 1 rather than 0 depending on the order of the sorted elements. If _stringcard_ is sorted of course exchange the roles

Comment: After the two loops, you have to _do_ something with the value `allmatch` (e.g.) print it, not just _set_ it. I've edited the example to reflect this.

Comment: @bruno Yes--I've edited the code to cache the value. As far as pre-sorting, I'd say baby steps and do the straightforward dual loop version version first, rather than adding the complexity of a sort for a 13 element array. Otherwise, OP would need to state that the `stringcard` list would always be sorted. It's unlikely that `reds` would be sorted

Comment: when I compile it , i get an error at `if (curcard, reds[j]) == 0)`  and a warning at   `char *curcard = &stringcard[i];`

Comment: The `if` was a typo when I adjusted the example [per bruno]. The 2nd was a lack of `const` in the declaration [which I'll fix]

Comment: @bruno I've added a pre-sorted version

Answer (score 0):

Given your other array is defined similarly, say `inputArray`, and both arrays are sorted before executing the following, then you could use code similar to:  (including number of elements

```
//Assumes both arrays are sorted before executing the following
char success = 1;
size_t size = sizeof(stringcard)/sizeof(stringcard[0]); 
size_t size2 = sizeof(inputArray)/sizeof(inputArray[0]);

if(size == size2)
{
    for(int i = 0; i<size;i++)
    {
        if(strcmp(stringcard[i], inputArray[i]) != 0)
        {
            success = 0;
            break;
        }
    }
{    
else
{
    success = 0;
}
//Proceed according to the value of success,
...
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However I am not allowed to use BOOL for the assignment. I should have mentioned it earlier

Comment: @momonosuke just replace BOOL by int, FALSE by 0 and TRUE by 1

Comment: @ryyker "if(strcmp(stringcard[i], inputArray[i]) != 0) { success = 0; break; }" it is useless to continue to compare when _success_ set to false/0

Comment: BTW as it was said the order may not be the same, that solution supposes it is the same

Comment: @bruno - Thanks for pointing that out.  I actually had a break in my test code, but failed to include it here :).  Edited with fix to that, and a comment about sorting.

Comment: @momonosuke - See edited code.  Replaced `BOOL` with `int`, with comments about sorting assumptions.

Answer (score 0):

Always try to use functions when possible.

```
int all_match(const char **table1, const char **table2, size_t t1size, size_t t2size)
{
    for(size_t t1index = 0; t1index < t1size; t1index++)
    {
        int match = 0;
        for(size_t t2index = 0; t2index < t2size; t2index++)
        {
            match = match || !strcmp(table1[t1index], table2[t2index]);
            if(match) break;
        }
        if(!match) return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However when I call the function and add a `printf("error")` und the `if(!match)`  it prints out an error even though the array `reds` contains all the elements of the `stringcard`

Comment: do not add anything to the function. Just call it.  Your "adds" ruined it.

Comment: I just found out why the strings in reds contain '\n' at the end for example 'REDA\n'

Comment: remove them with the function I wrote for you in your previous topic.

Comment: If i add '\n' at the end of each string in the stringcard array it doesn't print out any error

Comment: sorry for bothering you, but I don't quit understand this part of the code `match = match || !strcmp(table1[t1index], table2[t2index]);`